# How to get a particular property of all child entities as list in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a parent class :

```
public class User {
    Long id;
    String name;

    @OneToMany(...)
    List<Role> roles
    ...
}
```

A Role class:

```
public class Role {
    Long roleId;
    Long roleName;
}
```

Can I query the `user` table using `Hibernate Query Language` to get a response like this:

```
public class ResponseModel {
    Long userId;
    Long userName;
    List<String> roleNames;
}
```

Basically, I want some of the properties of `user` and only the `roleNames` of user and not the whole rich objects of `Role`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use join hql and [ResultTransformer](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/transform/ResultTransformer.html)

**UPDATED**

Example below returns a list of ResponseModels but not exactly what you would need.

It just starting point to understand how you can get only required fields.

```
List<ResponseModel> responseModel = session
            .createQuery(
                    "select u.userId, r.roleId, r.roleName from User u join Role r ")
            .setResultTransformer(
                    new ResultTransformer() {
                        @Override
                        public Object transformTuple(
                                Object[] tuple,
                                String[] aliases) {
                            return new ResponseModel(
                                    (Long) tuple[0],
                                    (Long) tuple[1]
                                    (String) tuple[2]
                            );
                        }

                        @Override
                        public List transformList(List collection) {
                            return collection;
                        }
                    }
            )
            .getResultList();
```

Comment: This won't do the job as it doesn't aggregate the role names into a collection. Might be used as a starting point, though.

Comment: @user2612030 yes, you are right. To get list of roles he should use another query or convert returned list. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using HQL you can use **Criteria** to get the values as a User Object.

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(User.class);
    criteria.setFetchMode("roles", FetchMode.SELECT);
```

From the **Criteria** list you can get the names of Roles you need.

```
User user = (User)criteria.list().get(0);

List<Role> roleList = user.getRoles();

List<String> roleNames = new ArrayList();

for(Role role : roleList)
{

roleNames.add(role.getRoleName());

}


ResponseModel responseModel = new ResponseModel();
responseModel.setUserID(user.getID());
responseModel.setUserName(user.getName());
responseModel.setRoleName(roleNames);
```

Comment: This reads the entire objects, so from a performance perspective it is no better than a similar HQL with a fetch clause.